# Converting file with single field into multiple comma separated fields

Tags: shell

I have a .dat file in which there is no delimiter between fields.

Eg: 2014HELLO2500

I have to convert the file into a comma separated file with commas at specific positions

i.e 2014,HELLO,2500

I could convert the file using for loop. But can it be done using a single command.

I tried using --output-delimiter option of cut command. But it does not work.

I am using AIX OS.

Thanks

Comment: Is your input file always in the same format?

Comment: The record I gave in the question is just for example. My file has records that has to be split into 15 fields

Comment: And how are we supposed to know where to make the splits?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your field widths are known, you can use `gawk` like this:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="4 5 4 ..." -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5...}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using awk

Assuming that you know the lengths of the fields, say, for example, 4 characters for the first field and 5 for the second, then try this:

```
$ awk -v s='4 5' 'BEGIN{n=split(s,a)} {pos=1; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%s,",substr($0,pos,a[i]); pos+=a[i]}; print substr($0,pos)}' file
2014,HELLO,2500
```

As an example of the exact same code but applied with many fields, consider this test file:

```
$ cat alphabet
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Let's divide it up:

```
$ awk -v s='1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2' 'BEGIN{n=split(s,a)} {pos=1; for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%s,",substr($0,pos,a[i]); pos+=a[i]}; print substr($0,pos)}' alphabet
A,BC,DEF,GH,I,JK,LMN,OP,Q,RS,TUV,WX,YZ
```

How it works:

- `-v s='1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2'`

  This creates a variable `s` which defines the lengths of all but the last field.  (There is no need to specify a length of the last field.)
- `BEGIN{n=split(s,a)}`

  This converts the string variable `s` to an array with each number as an element of the array.
- `pos=1`

  At the beginning of each line, we initialize the position variable, `pos`, to the value `1`.
- `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf "%s,",substr($0,pos,a[i]); pos+=a[i]}`

  For each element in array `a`, we print the required number of characters starting at position `pos` followed by a comma.  After each print, we increment position `pos` so that the next print will start with the next character.
- `print substr($0,pos)`

  We print the last field on the line using however many character are left after position `pos`.

### Using sed

Assuming that you know the lengths of the fields, say, for example, 4 characters for the first field and 5 for the second, then try this:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{4})(.{5})/\1,\2,/' file
2014,HELLO,2500
```

This approach can be used for up to nine fields at a time.  To get 15 fields, two passes would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a delimiter always between characters and number then you can use this:

```
$ sed -r -e 's/([A-Za-z])([0-9])/\1,\2/g' -e 's/([0-9])([A-Za-z])/\1,\2/g' <<< "2014HELLO2500"
2014,HELLO,2500
$
```

Answer (score 0):

When numbers and strings alternate, you can use
echo "2014HELLO2500other_string121312Other_word10" |

```
   sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g; s/\([0-9]\)\([A-Za-z]\)/\1,\2/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo TEP_CHECK.20180627023645.txt | cut -d'.' -f2 | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="_"} {print substr($1,1,4),substr($1,5,2),substr($1,7,2),substr($1,9,2),substr($1,11,2),substr($1,13,2)}'
```

Output:

```
2018_06_27_02_36_45
```